# Why and when should the NonSerializable Attribute used?

Tags: c#, serialization

I'm recently learning C# serialization myself. I noticed the `[NonSerializable]` Attribute and wonderd why it should/could/must be used and what the reasons for that could be.

---

Here are some of my research sites I used:

- [Benefits of NonSerialized when Serializable is not used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3735926/benefits-of-nonserialized-when-serializable-is-not-used)
- [MSDN article about the NonSerializable attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nonserializedattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (contains an example but no reason why it should/shouldn't be used)

---

### Actual questions:

- Are there examples which seriously can't be serialized (theoretical and practical)?
- Why should/n't it be used?

Comment: You may sometimes not want to serialize some vulnerable data like a password, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I utilize attributes to prevent serialization, it's typically because I want to secure data, or it because it wouldn't make sense to serialize a given field (maybe one that isn't itself serializable, or something that gets initialized every time the class is instantiated).

For example, say I had a record I wanted to save that is associated with a user. I may want to save their name, but never their password:

```
[Serializable]
public struct User
{
    public string Name;
    //this should never be persisted
    [NonSerialized]
    public string Password;
}

//when I persist this, it persists the CreatedBy User without the password
[Serializable]
public class Record
{
    //password won't be persisted now
    public User CreatedBy{ get; set; }

    //other information I want to save
}
```

Other times, I may have a non-serializable property that I don't want saved or sent across the wire after serialization.

```
[Serializable]
public class Whatever
{
     public Whatever()
     {
         //this always gets new-ed up, so there's no point in persisting it.
         //maybe it's not even serializable!
         HelperUtility = InitHelper();
     }

     //no sense in serializing this helper utility
     [NonSerialized]
     public NonSerializableClass HelperUtility;

     //but I may want to actually save this!
     public string DataIActuallyWantToSave;
}
```

That's the gist.

Such attributes do actually see use in the real world, and I've used them many times.

Answer (score 2):

I can think of a few reasons why not to serialize some fields, for example when:

  - they contain an unencrypted vulnerable data like a password, pin etc.,

  - they are used to store uncompressed data (eg bitmap) and there's a field containing the compressed equivalent available,

  - they are created in the object constructor (eg timer).